# Fatal mySQL error while trying to access DVWA

Tags: mysql

I am trying to setup DVWA and I did all the steps according to this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cak2lQvBRAo) till renaming the config file to config.nic.php and changing the password field to blank.

Something like this-

```
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = '127.0.0.1'; 
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa'; 
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'dvwa'; 
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';
$_DVWA[ 'db_port'] = '3306';
```

I get the error on this page (http://127.0.0.1/login.php)-

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown database 'dvwa' in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\includes\dvwaPage.inc.php:499 
> Stack trace: 
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\includes\dvwaPage.inc.php(499): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'USE dvwa') 
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php(8): dvwaDatabaseConnect() 
> #2 {main} 
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\includes\dvwaPage.inc.php on line 499

Can't even access the DVWA setup. I am using XAMPP and the Apache2 (ports 80, 443) and mySQL (port 3306) are running fine. Please help!

Comment: The error message seems to be clear. You never created the `dvwa` database in your MySQL database.

Comment: This is done by the `"Create / Reset Database" button in the database setup page. The video shows this starting at 10:00.

Comment: Typo: `config.nic.php` should be `config.inc.php`

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo here as nic but it's config.inc.php in my files and it doesn't even show the setup page to push the button "Create/Reset Database". It shows a white screen with this message. With http://127.0.0.1/DVWA/ in the address bar, I can see the Index of DVWA though, with folder names listed there (Parent directory, css/, images/, includes/, js/). When clicking the parent directory, it returns me to the white screen with the same error message and in the address bar, it's- http://127.0.0.1/login.php . I am using Windows 10 Home, and happens on all browsers (Edge, FireFox etc).

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer for you.
Try localhost/dvwa/setup.php on browser
Then click on create or reset database and it should get to login page
Remember user name and password must be same as what you configured in config.php

Good luck